# How to setup a Masstransit Order state machine?

Tags: c#, asp.net, rabbitmq, microservices, masstransit

I have this simple process for my order process spanning multiple microservices.
Created > validated> Checkout session created > payed > collected. The result can fail at any step resulting in the "Cancelled" state.
I currently have the following as my state machine:

```
    {
        public Event<IOrderCreatedEvent> StartOrderProcess { get; private set; }
        public Event<IOrderValidatedEvent> OrderValidated { get; private set; }
        public Event<IOrderCheckoutSessionCreatedEvent> CheckoutSessionCreatedEvent { get; private set; }
        public Event<IOrderPayedEvent> OrderPayed { get; private set; }
        public Event<IOrderCollectedEvent> OrderCollected { get; private set; }
        public Event<IOrderCancelledEvent> OrderCancelled { get; private set; }

        public State Validated { get; private set; }
        public State CheckoutSessionCreated { get; private set; }
        public State Payed { get; private set; }
        public State Collected { get; private set; }

        public State Cancelled { get; private set; }

        
        //Start => Validated => Session created => Payed => Collected 
        public OrderStateMachine()
        {
            InstanceState(s => s.CurrentState);
            Event(() => StartOrderProcess, x => x.CorrelateById(m => m.Message.OrderId));
            Event(() => OrderValidated, x => x.CorrelateById(m => m.Message.OrderId));
            Event(() => CheckoutSessionCreatedEvent, x => x.CorrelateById(m => m.Message.OrderId));
            Event(() => OrderPayed, x => x.CorrelateById(m => m.Message.OrderId));
            Event(() => OrderCollected, x => x.CorrelateById(m => m.Message.OrderId));

            Event(() => OrderCancelled, x => x.CorrelateById(m => m.Message.OrderId));

            //Start
            Initially(
                When(StartOrderProcess)
                    .Then(context =>
                    {
                        context.Instance.OrderId = context.Data.OrderId;
                        context.Instance.PackagesId = context.Data.PackagesIds;
                    })
                    .Publish(context => new OrderValidatedEvent(context.Instance))
                    .TransitionTo(Validated)
            );

            //Validated => payment session created
            During(Validated, When(
                    CheckoutSessionCreatedEvent).Then(context =>
                {
                    context.Instance.OrderId = context.Data.OrderId;
                    context.Instance.PackagesId = context.Data.PackagesIds;
                    context.Instance.CheckoutSessionId = context.Data.SessionId;
                })
                .Publish(context => new OrderCheckoutSessionCreatedEvent(context.Instance))
                .TransitionTo(CheckoutSessionCreated)
            );
            
            //Session created => payed
            During(CheckoutSessionCreated, When(
                    OrderPayed).Then(context =>
                {
                    context.Instance.OrderId = context.Data.OrderId;
                    context.Instance.PackagesId = context.Data.PackagesIds;
                    context.Instance.PaymentMethod = context.Data.PaymentMethod;
                })
                .Publish(context => new OrderPayedEvent(context.Instance))
                .TransitionTo(Payed)
            );
            
            //payed => Collected
            During(Payed, When(
                    OrderCollected).Then(context =>
                {
                    context.Instance.OrderId = context.Data.OrderId;
                    context.Instance.PackagesId = context.Data.PackagesIds;
                    context.Instance.OrderCollectedDateTime = DateTime.Now;
                })
                .Publish(context => new OrderCollectedEvent(context.Instance))
                .TransitionTo(Collected)
            );
            //Cancel order bij cancelled event
            DuringAny(
                When(OrderCancelled)
                    .Then(context =>
                    {
                        context.Instance.OrderCancelDateTime = DateTime.Now;
                        context.Instance.OrderId = context.Data.OrderId;
                    })
                    .Finalize());


            SetCompletedWhenFinalized();
        }
    }
```

And this is the content of "OrderStateData"

```
    public class OrderStateData : SagaStateMachineInstance
    {
        public Guid CorrelationId { get; set; }
        public string CurrentState { get; set; }
        public DateTime? OrderCreationDateTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime? OrderCancelDateTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime? OrderCollectedDateTime { get; set; }

        public Guid OrderId { get; set; }
        public List<Guid> PackagesId { get; set; }
        public string CheckoutSessionId { get; set; }
        public string PaymentMethod { get; set; }
    }
```

However when I try to use this I get the following error

```
      R-FAULT rabbitmq://localhost/Constants.OrderBus1 5f750000-61e0-00d8-0485-08d8c20620a5 MessagingContracts.Orders.IOrderValidatedEvent FS_Saga.OrderStateMachine.OrderStateData(00:00:00.1109663)
      Automatonymous.NotAcceptedStateMachineException: FS_Saga.OrderStateMachine.OrderStateData(654b5d93-cb5a-4f58-a06c-3a25ac56532d) Saga exception on receipt of MessagingContracts.Orders.IOrderValidatedEvent: Not accepted in state Validated
       ---> Automatonymous.UnhandledEventException: The OrderValidated event is not handled during the Validated state for the OrderStateMachine state machine
         at Automatonymous.AutomatonymousStateMachine`1.DefaultUnhandledEventCallback(UnhandledEventContext`1 context)
         at Automatonymous.AutomatonymousStateMachine`1.UnhandledEvent(EventContext`1 context, State state)
         at Automatonymous.States.StateMachineState`1.Automatonymous.State<TInstance>.Raise[T](EventContext`2 context)
         at Automatonymous.AutomatonymousStateMachine`1.Automatonymous.StateMachine<TInstance>.RaiseEvent[T](EventContext`2 context)
         at Automatonymous.Pipeline.StateMachineSagaMessageFilter`2.Send(SagaConsumeContext`2 context, IPipe`1 next)
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
         at Automatonymous.Pipeline.StateMachineSagaMessageFilter`2.Send(SagaConsumeContext`2 context, IPipe`1 next)
         at Automatonymous.Pipeline.StateMachineSagaMessageFilter`2.Send(SagaConsumeContext`2 context, IPipe`1 next)
         at MassTransit.Saga.SendSagaPipe`2.Send(SagaRepositoryContext`2 context)
         at MassTransit.Saga.SendSagaPipe`2.Send(SagaRepositoryContext`2 context)
         at MassTransit.Saga.InMemoryRepository.InMemorySagaRepositoryContextFactory`1.Send[T](ConsumeContext`1 context, IPipe`1 next)
         at MassTransit.Saga.Pipeline.Filters.CorrelatedSagaFilter`2.GreenPipes.IFilter<MassTransit.ConsumeContext<TMessage>>.Send(ConsumeContext`1 context, IPipe`1 next)
```

I have a strong feeling my state machine is absolute garbage, but I cant find anything on how to set it up properly.

Comment: I don't think you need to handle the `OrderValidated` event, since it's publish but not used by the state machine. You may try removing it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a `OrderValidated` event is occurring while the state is `Validated` - which is currently unhandled (only `CheckoutSessionCreatedEvent` is handled at the moment). It is important to note that even though publishing the `OrderValidated` event is technically occurring prior to the transition to `Validated`, the consumption of the event is occurring after the transition to `Validated` state (we're dealing with message brokers here).

Basically, your behavior logic is expecting a `When(OrderValidated)` within `During(Validated)`. E.g.,

```
            //Validated => payment session created
            During(Validated, When(
                    CheckoutSessionCreatedEvent).Then(context =>
                {
                    context.Instance.OrderId = context.Data.OrderId;
                    context.Instance.PackagesId = context.Data.PackagesIds;
                    context.Instance.CheckoutSessionId = context.Data.SessionId;
                })
                .Publish(context => new OrderCheckoutSessionCreatedEvent(context.Instance))
                .TransitionTo(CheckoutSessionCreated),
                When(OrderValidated).Then({ /* Do some stuff */ });
```

Chris is right in his comment though, it looks like you should remove the `OrderValidated` event if your not going to be used for anything.

If you're half-way through something you could always just temporarily ignore the event using `Ignore`. E.g.,

```
            //Validated => payment session created
            During(Validated, When(
                    CheckoutSessionCreatedEvent).Then(context =>
                {
                    context.Instance.OrderId = context.Data.OrderId;
                    context.Instance.PackagesId = context.Data.PackagesIds;
                    context.Instance.CheckoutSessionId = context.Data.SessionId;
                })
                .Publish(context => new OrderCheckoutSessionCreatedEvent(context.Instance))
                .TransitionTo(CheckoutSessionCreated),
                Ignore(OrderValidatedEvent));
```

Hopefully this makes sense. Correct me if I'm wrong @Chris Patterson.